# How to upload a directory to HDFS

Tags: python, rest, hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I'm working on a project where I need to upload a directory via REST API from a machine outside my Hadoop cluster, to the HDFS. Basically, I need a command where I can, via terminal (or Python script), send a directory to the HDFS, using the REST API.

The only way that is specified in the WebHDFS documentation is the upload of a single file. That is not sufficient for me, because I need to upload thousands of files via REST API.

Thanks in advance!

This is for a HDFS using a single node as NameNode and DataNode, very default configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating an empty directory first:

```
curl -i -s --user your_username:your_password --max-time 45 -X PUT https://XXXXX:8443/gateway/default/webhdfs/v1/user/path_to_directory?op=MKDIRS
```

Then you can upload files:

```
curl -i -L -s --user your_username:your_password --max-time 45 -X PUT -T file_name.txt \ https://XXXXX:8443/gateway/default/webhdfs/v1/user/path_to_director/path_to_file/file_name?op=CREATE
```

Ref: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/AnalyticsEngine?topic=AnalyticsEngine-upload-files-hdfs